# How to find performance bottlenecks with Spring Data Redis and local Redis server

Tags: java, performance, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I am trying to optimize performance on fetching data from Redis. The server is currently running locally on my 2015 Macbook Pro.

**First: Problem explanation**
For the time being I only have 32 keys stored as hashes. 16 of these store quite long JSON strings in every hash value with <300 fields in each hash. The rest are quite small, so I don't have any problems with them.

From a Spring Boot application, using the Spring Data Redis template, with a Jedis connection, the total time to retrieve the 16 big hashes is ~1700ms by pipelining 4 HGETALL commands 4 times.

**My question:**
How do I proceed to find the real bottlenecks? I have already checked the SLOWLOG, which tells me the actions performed on the server are very fast, < 1ms per HGETALL command, which is to be expected. This means the bottleneck has to be between the Java application and the Redis server. Is it possible that the latency is the cause of the other ~1650ms? (Latency doesn't seem to be a problem with the other smaller hashes.) Or could it be the deserialization of my JSON strings? I am not sure how I can test this as I have no way to put in timers in the RedisTemplate code.

Below is the code I use to pipeline the HGETALL commands:

```
private Map<Date, Map<Integer, Departure>> pipelineMethod(List<String> keys, String keyspace) {

    long pipeTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<Object> results = redisTemplate.executePipelined(
            (RedisCallback) (connection) -> {
                for (String key : keys) {
                    long actionTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    connection.hGetAll((keyspace + key).getBytes());
                    System.out.println("HGETALL finished in " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-actionTime) + "ms");
                }

                return null;
            }
    );
    System.out.println("Pipeline finished in " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-pipeTime) + "ms");

    Map<Date, Map<Integer, Departure>> resultMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
        if (results.get(i) == null) {
            resultMap.put(new Date(Long.parseLong(keys.get(i))), null);
            log.debug("Hash map from redis on " + new Date(Long.parseLong(keys.get(i))) + " was null on retrieval");
        }
        else
            resultMap.put(new Date(Long.parseLong(keys.get(i))), (Map<Integer, Departure>) results.get(i));
    }

    return resultMap;
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A good approach is to start with the simple-most setup, measure latency/throughput and incrementing complexity (= adding code/features( from there on. Please take warming/initialization into account. In your case, you might want to use Jedis directly (for a test), then test with Spring Data Redis and then add JSON unmarshalling.

Comment: I am curious what you found out here. We experienced an issue where storing very large keys (and evicting them very quickly due to updates) caused major bottlenecks. In our case the network connector between our server and redis instance was too restricted and could not send MB of data with the throughput needed. Opening that up ameliorated the issue while we refactored our redis design.

Answer (score -1):

try using lettuce client with connection pool

```
  private GenericObjectPoolConfig getPoolConfig() {
    GenericObjectPoolConfig poolConfig = new GenericObjectPoolConfig();
    //All below should use the propertysources;
    poolConfig.setMaxTotal(20);
    poolConfig.setMaxIdle(20);
    poolConfig.setMinIdle(0);
    return poolConfig;
  }      
     @Bean
      @Primary
      public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        DefaultLettucePool lettucePool = new DefaultLettucePool(redisHost, Integer.valueOf(redisPort).intValue(), getPoolConfig());
        lettucePool.setPassword(redisPass);
        lettucePool.afterPropertiesSet();
        LettuceConnectionFactory clientConfig = new LettuceConnectionFactory(lettucePool);
        clientConfig.afterPropertiesSet();
        return clientConfig;
      }

      @Bean
      public RedisTemplate<?, ?> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<byte[], byte[]> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return template;
      }
```

Comment: any reason for change jedis to lettuce?